# Can't Add FieldVariable in Blockly

Tags: javascript, web, foreach, blockly

I'm trying to put a foreach loop into my web blockly interface but am getting weird error messages. When the block tries to load it shows a TypeError (TypeError: Blockly.Msg.DELETE_VARIABLE is undefined[Learn More]). This error goes away when I take away the FieldVariable for the for each loop. But I need some variable there. Do you have any insight as to how to create my own for each loop with Blockly and avoid these errors.

Here's the code:

```
Blockly.Blocks['for_each'] = {
    init: function () {
        this.appendValueInput("for_each_list")
            .setCheck(null)
            .appendField("for each item")
            .appendField(new Blockly.FieldVariable('node'), 
                          'for_each_variable')
            .appendField("in list");
        this.appendStatementInput("for_each_do")
            .setCheck(null)
            .appendField("do");
        this.setOutput(true, null);
        this.setColour(65);
        this.setTooltip('');
        this.setHelpUrl('');
    }
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the controls_forEach block: https://github.com/google/blockly/blob/master/blocks/loops.js#L191

Your problem may be that you don't have the messages file loaded.  Make sure you are also including msg/messages.js, as the playground does: https://github.com/google/blockly/blob/master/tests/playground.html#L52